# Is this asbestos cement board?

Tags: asbestos, cement-board

I accidentally broke this board in my store room, as I thought it is cardboard or gyprock as it’s already had a rough structure around it. My house was complete built in 1990. And I notice gyprock everywhere.

However after I broke it, I tap on it, it has a clicking sound. And send some to the lab, roughly 4g, the lab said insufficient samples and cannot identify it.

[image: suspicious board with dimples]

Comment: Send a sample for testing - be generous. As for if it contains asbestos all you will get here are guesses.

Comment: Might be, might not be, doesn't matter - if you leave it alone. If you're planning to rip it out, send enough for the lab to process.

Comment: Don't go sanding the stuff and then sniffing it. Worst case scenario if it is asbestos, put on properly PPE masks, remove the broken pieces, ventilate the area, and then stop breaking it off.